# How to count how many data points fall in a bin

Tags: python, sorting, bin

I have set the parameters of my bins and I want to find how to add one to the bin when a data point falls in the range of a particular bin, essentially count how many data points fall in each bin range, so that I can use that as the "frequency" when I graph it out.

My bins ranges are set by:

```
 bins = [(i*bin_width, (i+1)*bin_width) for i in range(num_bins)]
```

and my data looks something like:

```
2.55619101399
2.55619101399
2.55619101399
3.615
4.42745271008
2.55619101399
2.55619101399
2.55619101399
4.42745271008
3.615
2.55619101399
4.42745271008
5.71581687075
5.71581687075
3.615
2.55619101399
2.55619101399
2.55619101399
2.55619101399
2.55619101399
```

Comment: It sounds like you are asking how to do a histogram, or am I missing something?  Look up "histogram" ...

Comment: No I understand how to make a histogram, but does that automatically count the frequency in the bins?

Comment: I guess I really don't understand what you're asking ... "number of points in the bin" is exactly what a histogram gives you. What do you mean by "frequency"?

Comment: But histogram will graph it, and I don't want to graph the number of data points per bin, I want to manipulate that data before graphing, which is why I want to be able to have a  counter in each bin.

Comment: @Wana_B3_Nerd: I'm pretty sure Ajean is suggesting [`NumPy.histogram`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html), not `matplotlib.histogram`.

Comment: OK, I wrote a second answer explaining why `numpy.histogram` is exactly what you want, as Ajean said in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first, each of your `bins` is just a tuple of the start and end values of that bin, so there's no way to add anything to it. You could change each `bin` into, say, list of `[start, stop, 0]` instead of a tuple of `(start, stop)`, or, maybe even better, an object. Or, alternatively, you could keep a separate `bin_counts` list, parallel to the `bins` list, and, e.g., `zip` them up when needed.

Next, if each bin goes from `i * bin_width` to `(i+1) * bin_width`, then how do you get the `i` value from a data value? That's easy: the opposite of multiply is divide, so it's just `data_point // bin_width`.

So:

```
bin_counts = [0 for bin in bins]
for data_point in data_points:
    bin_number = data_point // bin_width
    bin_counts[bin_number] += 1
```

---

Showing one of the other options, because I think you were asking about it in the comments:

```
bins = [[i*bin_width, (i+1)*bin_width, 0] for i in range(num_bins)]
for data_point in data_points:
    bin_number = data_point // bin_width
    bins[bin_number][2] += 1
```

Here, each bin is a list of `[start, stop, count]`, instead of having a list of `(start, stop)` bins and a separate list of `count` values.

Comment: So I am a little confused on whats wrong with the way I am creating the bins, is your solution to just do:bins = list[(i*bin_width, (i+1)*bin_width) for i in range(num_bins),0] ?

Comment: @Wana_B3_Nerd: There's nothing _wrong_ with the way you're creating the bins, as long as you want `bins` to be an array of `(start, stop)` values. If you want them to be something different, then of course you should be creating that something different instead.

Comment: Okay so if I want to make the bins into the list format should I take off the "for I in range(num_bins) or just should it look like the format that I put in my first comment.

Comment: @Wana_B3_Nerd: I don't really understand what you're asking. The format in your first comment isn't even valid Python, and just taking off the `for i in range(num_bins)` just means you'll have a list of one `(start, stop)` bin instead of a list of `num_bins` of them… Does my updated answer help?

Comment: Yes it helps, but when I run it I get the error:TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable

Comment: @Wana_B3_Nerd: Without knowing what you're running, what the variables around it are holding, and where that error comes from (the traceback), it's hard to debug that. But the fact that you're using NumPy changes things. If you ever find yourself creating lists instead of arrays with NumPy, or looping instead of broadcasting, you're probably doing something wrong. Especially if you're trying to do something very common, like binning values, that's likely to have a built-in solution in NumPy (or SciPy).

Answer (score 6):

Since you're using NumPy, you (a) shouldn't be trying to create lists and loop over them instead of using arrays, and (b) should look to see if what you want to do is already built-in (or available in SciPy or Pandas or some other library built on NumPy), because often it is.

And [`numpy.histogram`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) is exactly what you want.

It takes a total width rather than a bin width, but other than that, it's trivial to plug in the values you already have and get back the values you want:

```
hist, edges = np.histogram(
    data_points,
    bins=num_bins,
    range=(0, bin_width*num_bins),
    density=False)
```

The `hist` array will contain the counts for each bin (like `bin_counts` in my other answer), which is what you want to post-process and eventually graph.

The `edges`, you may or may not need. It's the same information as the `bins` in your original question, but in different format—instead of `[(0, .1), (.1, .2), (.2, .3)]` it's `[0, .1, .2, .3]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter

frequency_data = Counter()

    for d in data:
        new_bins = bins
        median = len(new_bins)/2
        while not new_bins[median][0] < d < new_bins[median][1]:
            if d < new_bins[median][0]:
                new_bins = new_bins[:median]
            elif d > new_bins[median][1]:
                new_bins = new_bins[median:]
            median = len(new_bins)/2
        frequency_data[new_bins[median]] += 1
```

Comment: Why make finding the bin O(N) instead of O(1)? Why use a dict when you have a contiguous index as your key? And why use `defaultdict` to make a `Counter` when you can just use `Counter` from the same module?

Comment: My concern was that using contiguous indexes in a list wouldn't handle bins of fractional size. For example (2.3, 2.4), size 0.1.

Comment: And the reasoning for default dict is that it adds a queried key if it does not find it, Counter does not.

Comment: `if bin[0] < d < bin[1]`. Also, you have better options for finding the bin to put an item in. You can binary search in O(logn) time or you can figure out a way to create the appropriate key and use a dict for O(1) lookup.

Comment: Re: "[defaultdict] adds a queried key if it does not find it, Counter does not". I don't know what you mean. Counter appears to work in the way you say it does not. ` >>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter()
>>> c["a"] += 4
>>> c
Counter({'a': 4})`

Comment: @Jonk: "My concern was that using contiguous indexes in a list wouldn't handle bins of fractional size." The OP has already solved that exact problem in his question: just multiply the bin number by the bin size to get the bin value; divide the value by the size to get the number.

Comment: @hughdbrown: Exactly, and it's specifically [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to do so: "Counter objects have a dictionary interface except that they return a zero count for missing items instead of raising a `KeyError`."

Comment: My mistake, you are correct about Counter. @hughdbrown: Out of curiosity, is my edit above what a typical binary search algorithm would look like for this problem?